# Passing permission through pending intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two applications. First application is passing pending intent to second. When first has reading call logs permission
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />` 
 and second has writing sd card permission  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` everything works fine. But When I write both the permissions in first app, the second is unable to write in sd card. Is it the wrong way to do so. Am I confusing sharing permissions through pending intent ? I am first time trying it so any help in welcome. Thank you

Comment: Why do you think you can share permissions between apps?

Comment: i think you are talking about two **activity** now applications

Comment: Well doesnt pending intent help us share permissions with foreign apps as if it was its own

Comment: @AMANSINGH no I have two applications

Answer (score 0):

I dear friend , in two words you can't share permissions, because when u declare which permissions needs your app, it'll be used in the future when android will run your app. Permissions and other data inserted in Manifest is for os and for market , for details please read this [Guide for Permissions](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/android-app-permissions/)

Comment: Okay But then practically what does pending intent provide more than a simple intent, I think it can't run a piece of code written in different app.

Comment: When you use PendingIntent you doesn't give permissions of your app to another app, Second app just can use Your Pending intent which are Activity, Broadcast or Service, so If your first App have A, B and C permissions, And you give Second app Pending intent which let to use permission 'C' , it doesn't mean that Second app will have permission C after, it means that Second app can use something which require permission C using your pending intent

Answer (score 0):

Is the application that has

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

in an application that is pre API level 16, because then you would need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

instead.

Comment: nope API level is higher, it works fine. No erros of permissions